# My account is banned from asking questions

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, post-ban

I don't understand why I take this message "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. Although, I asked my last question at 22 August and I have contributed positively to the site. I read the Help Center.

Comment: You can contact with the site MSE using the link Contact that you can find in the main page, below. Then maybe they can tell you what happen.

Comment: Thank you, I did.

Comment: You are welcome. Any case maybe some user want provide you more help from this META if it is possible.

Comment: Perhaps as a consequence of this ban, you seem to be turning to posting answers. Unfortunately, your three last ones, posted during the last 18 hours, are squarely subpar. Please change this.

Comment: I checked out some of your old questions. For example [this from December 2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1567505/11619). Looks to me that some key piece is missing. Why wouldn't the derivation be indentically zero? What's the point of asking the same question about two derivations when they are not connected in any way whatsoever? May be other questions suffer from similar problems? Anyway, this ban may feel a bit harsh, but there is room for improvement here, and that could help your cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, read everything in the following page.

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

This will tell you what you can do to try to get out of a question ban. Note in particular that this is an automated system, and moderators do not create or remove this ban.

Since you've asked, you might benefit from knowing why your account has a question ban. You have asked a total of 29 questions. 13 of these questions have been deleted. An additional one question is closed. 23 of these questions have vote score 0 or less. This is a pretty poor record.

Looking at your two most recent (not deleted) question ([one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402209/field-extension-of-domain) and [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693161/multilinear-map-with-algebra)), I notice some patterns that might explain some downvotes.

- Both have poor titles that don't indicate the content of the question.

  Using a more informative title would better attract people who might answer your question, and it will be easier for later visitors to the site to find this question to answer their own worries.
- Both have misspelled words and atypical formatting.

  Using correct spelling and grammar (if possible) makes it much more likely that others will bother reading the question. Many people don't read poorly formatted posts, as it's an immediate indicator that the asker hasn't put in much effort into the question.
- Both questions are pretty vague.

  I'm not sure what either of these last two questions are actually about. It's much better if each post is centered around a single, well-defined question. Initially it may be easier to really emphasize this single question. Providing some context and explaining what you've thought about concerning the problem can help indicate to others exactly what you're having trouble with, as well as help others know exactly what the question is.

Reading other well-received questions is a good idea to understand what sorts of questions are or are not well-received here.